# Crear efecto wrap para option demasiado largo en select

Tags: javascript, html, css

Saludos tengo un dropdown con algunas option demasiado largos, me gustaria crear el efecto wrap para dichos option o a su vez alguna otra alternativa, he intentado esto:

```css
option {
  word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

```html
<select name="" id="">
  <option value="" select disabled>------------</option>
  <option value="">ENERGIA ELECTRICA</option>
  <option value="">ACTIVIDADES DE CONSTRUCCIÓN DE OBRA MATERIAL INMUEBLE, URBANIZACIÓN, LOTIZACIÓN O ACTIVIDADES SIMILARES</option>
  <option value="">INVERSIONES ENTRE INSTITUCIONES DEL SISTEMA FINANCIERO Y ENTIDADES ECONOMÍA POPULAR Y SOLIDARIA</option>
  <option value="">PAGOS Y CRÉDITOS EN CUENTA EFECTUADOS POR EL BCE Y LOS DEPÓSITOS CENTRALIZADOS DE VALORES, EN CALIDAD DE INTERMEDIARIOS, A INSTITUCIONES DEL SISTEMA FINANCIERO POR CUENTA DE OTRAS INSTITUCIONES DEL SISTEMA FINANCIERO</option>

</select>
```

No se de que manera podria lograrlo agradeceria cualquier sugerencia..gracias..!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Algo así entonces con `JavaScript` y la función `slice`

```js
function myFunction() {
  var options = document.getElementsByTagName("option");
  var limite = 30;
  
  for(var i = 0; i < options.length; i++){
    options[i].setAttribute('title', options[i].innerText); // para poder ver el texto completo en el hover del elemento antes de cortarlo
    options[i].innerText = options[i].innerText.slice(0, limite) + '...';
  }
}

window.onload = () => myFunction();
```

```html
<select name="" id="mySelect">
  <option value="" select disabled>------------</option>
  <option value="">ENERGIA ELECTRICA</option>
  <option value="">ACTIVIDADES DE CONSTRUCCIÓN DE OBRA MATERIAL INMUEBLE, URBANIZACIÓN, LOTIZACIÓN O ACTIVIDADES SIMILARES</option>
  <option value="">INVERSIONES ENTRE INSTITUCIONES DEL SISTEMA FINANCIERO Y ENTIDADES ECONOMÍA POPULAR Y SOLIDARIA</option>
  <option value="">PAGOS Y CRÉDITOS EN CUENTA EFECTUADOS POR EL BCE Y LOS DEPÓSITOS CENTRALIZADOS DE VALORES, EN CALIDAD DE INTERMEDIARIOS, A INSTITUCIONES DEL SISTEMA FINANCIERO POR CUENTA DE OTRAS INSTITUCIONES DEL SISTEMA FINANCIERO</option>
</select>
```

Comment: de igual manera sale el option demasiado grande, el select esta bien porque uso bootstrap y determino el tamaño con col-md-3..etc..

Comment: Te agregue un nuevo ejemplo con javascript

Answer (score 1):

Aquí una mezcla con jquery, jquery ui y el plugin de jquery: selectboxit

```js
$(function(){

    //Inicializamos el plugin con las opciones
    $("#testselectset").selectBoxIt({
        theme: "default",
        defaultText: "Make a selection...",
        autoWidth: false
    });

    //lanzamos evento en cada cambio, esto en caso se requiera.
    $("#testselectset").change(function(){
        alert("You selected: "+this.value+" from the Selectboxit plugin");
    });
       
});
```

```css
.selectboxit-container .selectboxit, .selectboxit-container .selectboxit-options {
  width: 600px; /* Width of the dropdown button */
  border-radius:0;
  max-height:540px;
}

.selectboxit-options .selectboxit-option .selectboxit-option-anchor {
    white-space: normal;
    min-height: 30px;
    height: auto;
}
```

```html
<link href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.selectboxit/3.3.0/jquery.selectBoxIt.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<section style="background-color:rgb(237.247.249);">
    <h2>Crear efecto wrap para option demasiado largo usando SelectboxIt plugin</h2>
    <select name="select_this" id="testselectset">
   <option value="" select disabled>------------</option>
  <option value="">ENERGIA ELECTRICA</option>
  <option value="">ACTIVIDADES DE CONSTRUCCIÓN DE OBRA MATERIAL INMUEBLE, URBANIZACIÓN, LOTIZACIÓN O ACTIVIDADES SIMILARES</option>
  <option value="">INVERSIONES ENTRE INSTITUCIONES DEL SISTEMA FINANCIERO Y ENTIDADES ECONOMÍA POPULAR Y SOLIDARIA</option>
  <option value="">PAGOS Y CRÉDITOS EN CUENTA EFECTUADOS POR EL BCE Y LOS DEPÓSITOS CENTRALIZADOS DE VALORES, EN CALIDAD DE INTERMEDIARIOS, A INSTITUCIONES DEL SISTEMA FINANCIERO POR CUENTA DE OTRAS INSTITUCIONES DEL SISTEMA FINANCIERO</option>

    </select>
    </section>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.selectboxit/3.3.0/jquery.selectBoxIt.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Quizás lo que necesitas usar en es la propiedad `text-overflow: ellipsis` en tu css.

https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/text-overflow