# Como aplicar un word-wrap dentro de un select-option? con css y html

Tags: javascript, html, css

Tengo el siguiente codigo donde el contenido de los `option`s se desbordan y no se puede ver el resto del contenido.

He tratado de hacerlo de la siguiente manera sin resultado alguno. **Ej:**

```css
div.po{
  width:245px;
  height: auto;
  word-wrap: break-word;
}
select{
  height: 220px;
  width:250px;
}
```

```html
<select multiple>
    <option><div class="po">1 .-Lorem Ipsum es simplemente el texto de relleno de las imprentas y archivos de texto. Lorem Ipsum ha sido el texto de relleno estándar de las industrias desde el año 1500</div></option>
    <option><div class="po">2 .-Lorem Ipsum es simplemente el texto de relleno de las imprentas y archivos de texto. Lorem Ipsum ha sido el texto de relleno estándar de las industrias desde el año 1500</div></option>
    <option><div class="po">3 .-Lorem Ipsum es simplemente el texto de relleno de las imprentas y archivos de texto. Lorem Ipsum ha sido el texto de relleno estándar de las industrias desde el año 1500</div></option>
    
</select>
```

Revise algunas preguntas como esta: [Crear efecto wrap para option demasiado largo en select](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/243504/crear-efecto-wrap-para-option-demasiado-largo-en-select) , pero no me sirve en absoluto ya que necesito que todo el texto sea leido por el usuario.

> como poner el formato `word-wrap: break-word;` en etiquetas options?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Necesitas usar `white-space: normal;` asi:

```css
select option{
  width:200px;
  height: auto;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  white-space: normal;
}
select{
  height: 220px;
  width:250px;
}
```

```html
<select multiple>
    <option><div class="po">1 .-Lorem Ipsum es simplemente el texto de relleno de las imprentas y archivos de texto. Lorem Ipsum ha sido el texto de relleno estándar de las industrias desde el año 1500</div></option>
    <option><div class="po">2 .-Lorem Ipsum es simplemente el texto de relleno de las imprentas y archivos de texto. Lorem Ipsum ha sido el texto de relleno estándar de las industrias desde el año 1500</div></option>
    <option><div class="po">3 .-Lorem Ipsum es simplemente el texto de relleno de las imprentas y archivos de texto. Lorem Ipsum ha sido el texto de relleno estándar de las industrias desde el año 1500</div></option>
    
</select>
```

Comment: Joder!!!  que PRO. ya ni son necesarios los `divs` internos, mil gracias.